# What if I never call get on the future from an Async Data Store operation?

Tags: google-app-engine

If I call an async data store operation such as the one shown below but then end the request without calling get on the future, what will happen?

Will my operation still execute?
Will me response be sent before the operation has completed execution?

```
AsyncDatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getAsyncDatastoreService();
Entity entity = new Employee("Employee", "Alfred");
// ... populate entity properties

// Make a sync call via the async interface
datastore.put(key)
//Return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rpc will be sent immediately; when your app is ready to send a response to the client, it will block until the rpc is done.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in python by accident and the result was nothing was written to the datastore.

Your operation may still execute but it seems that'll happen only if the response handler is still active when it decides to execute. If not, nothing seems to happen at all.

Yes, the response will be sent before the operation has completed execution - this is the main feature of a future, it's non-blocking.

Comment: I didn't mention it in the question but yes this is Java specific.